jmeter-plugins.org is not available, is there any alternative site to get jpgc-webdriver?
I'm using https://jmeter-plugins.org/ to download jpgc-webdriver (jpgc-webdriver-3.1.zip) but whole site went offline last week (at least since 30th July).
Is there any alternative site to download that kind of plugins?
archive.org does not have any snpashot for https://jmeter-plugins.org/ (which is strage btw)

The site went online about 12 hours ago, but I'm still concerned about not having an alternative to be able to get the plugins.
